# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource: order of message files matters?

Tags: java, spring, message

I use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` for handling localised messages. I use `sci-xxx.properties` for english (default) and `sci-xxx_de.properties` for de german version.

I have a junit test, that checks, that a message has been resolved to english version. Locally it works always good.
Trick is, on CI (Jenkins) it fails - the german version is loaded, even though during call to

```
resourceBundleMessageSource.getMessage(code, params, resolveLocale());
```

the call to `resolveLocale()` returns "en".

The difference I found, is the `resourceBundleMessageSource.toString()` output. Locally it shows  the list of files alpha-ordered. On CI it is mixed, and the commons_de file, that contains my test message comes BEFORE the default file:

```
basenames=[messages/sci-commons_de,messages/sci-commons,messages/sci-user,messages/sci-user_de]
```

So I moved my german message from commons_de to user_de, that is loaded at the end. Guess what - now the test is green.

And I am really confused... Is the file order really important? How can I force the correct order? Or am I missing sth?

I belive, the CI server has german locale, but it should be overriden by my `resolveLocale()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappearde, when I renamed files from _de to _de_DE and used "two part" Locale enums de_DE and en_US in resolveLocale()